# Setting up AzuraCast (Radio broadcast) on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, virtual-machine, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04

I am setting up a web radio station with AzuraCast. I just created an instance (Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 20.04) and successfully set all parameters. I can access my radio station through the external IP Google Cloud offers and through a subdomain I already owned on Google Domains. Everything seems ok up to here. However, I found two problems that make wonder whether a VM on Google Cloud is the right way to go for my projects.

1. I only get to access the server(AzuraCast via external IP) with no SSL / HTTPS protocol. Whenever I configure the service to only work on such encryption, I get warnings about accessing a risky website. The only solution I found was disabling the SSL and using the old HTTP to access the web radio station. I set up LETS ENCRYPT on the VM Ubuntu OS though it seems not to provide a different certificate other than the self signed one that any browser rejects.
2. I want to provide my partners with credentials to log in on to the radio station website to broadcast their live sessions. We have already done it with other services. However, I can't get the software installed on my PC to connect to the station. Butt says 'Connecting' and nothing else happens. Mixxx sends an error 'Socket is busy' and never connects. I have previously used Mixxx with AzuraCast so I know how to set it up. It seems like the Google VM External IP doesn't accept connections from Mixxx. I would normally do the port forwarding thing on a local network, but I don't know if the external ip already has open ports or how to do that if needed.

I'm sorry to have written the story of my life here. Hope to have added what you guys need to guide me. I some times think Google Cloud VMs are a little too much for what I want to do. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance for your big help!

Comment: You have something wrong with your AzuraCast SSL cert configuration. Please run `docker-compose logs nginx_proxy_letsencrypt` on your GCP VM and update your question with the output of that command.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the AzuraCast configuration.

Fallow some troubleshooting for this software.

First make sure your Azuracast is set up to serve content on ports 809 & 443.
Second - make sure your GCP firewall allows traffic on those ports for this machine.

Make sure Let's Encrypt is enabled:

> Connect to your host server via a terminal (SSH) connection and
>
> ````
> cd /var/azuracast ./docker.sh update-self ./docker.sh
> letsencrypt-create```
> ````

Still not working ?

> The first thing that you should do when you have set up Let's Encrypt as described above and you still see AzuraCast serving a self-signed certificate is to restart AzuraCast via the following commands:
>
> `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`

Wait a couple of minutes and check again.

If you still see the self-signed certificate have a look at this artice on [how to install & enable LetsEncrypt cert's on AzuraCast](https://docs.azuracast.com/en/administration/ssl-and-lets-encrypt).

You may also have a look on a [documentation how to install the SSL certificates on na GCP VM.](https://techmonger.github.io/46/free-ssl-google-cloud/)